# Laravel query where date more recent than current time

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using a Laravel eloquent model.
I want to add a query condition `where start_time later than now`.

For example:

```
Model::whereAfterNow('start_time')->all()
```

Can you help me??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it looks like you need a query scope (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes).

assuming 'start_time' is a model property (database field) containing a some representation of time, and you want a scope that returns all models `where 'start_time' later than now`...

How you structure your code depends on what format your dates are stored in your database.

For example, if you are using epoch timestamps, then in your Model.php:

```
public function scopewhereAfterNow($query)
{
    return $query->where('start_time', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->timestamp);
}
```

or you could use the DB facade:

```
public function scopewhereAfterNow($query)
{
    return $query->where('start_time', '>', DB::raw('unix_timestamp(NOW())'));
}
```

which you might call like:
`$results = Model::whereAfterNow()->get();`

Comment: I have edited my answer to more accurately address your question.

Comment: you use  DB::raw('unix_timestamp(NOW())') query wich does not need and additional query in db

Comment: its not an additional query, its injected into the existing query as a string. see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 1):

If 'start_time' returns a DateTime string you can try:

```
Model::where('start_time', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())->get();
```

If 'start_time' only returns time then you can try:

```
Model::where('start_time', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toTimeString())->get();
```

Comment: You can use Model::where('start_time', '>', Carbon::now())->get();
But i dont wont use this structure